# Java doesn't use Paper Size Defined on printer settings on Windows

Tags: java, windows, printing, size

I have defined a custom paper size on windows printer settings that is is being ignored by the following java code:

```
public class Test {
    final static String fileName = "C:\\test.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException {
        java.util.Hashtable printers = new java.util.Hashtable();
        PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        printers.put("##DefaultPrinter##", ps);
        String printerToUse = "##DefaultPrinter##";
        printDoc(fileName, ps);
    }

    private static void printDoc(String fileName, PrintService ps) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException {
        FileInputStream fInput = null;
        DocFlavor[] docFlavor = ps.getSupportedDocFlavors();

        DocFlavor flavor = null;

        if (fileName.endsWith("txt")) {
            flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8;
            if (!ps.isDocFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                File bomFile = new File(fileName);
            }
        }
        if (flavor == null || !ps.isDocFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        }

        fInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        DocPrintJob pj = ps.createPrintJob();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fInput, flavor, null);

        pj.print(doc, null);

    }
}
```

When I print the content of  "C:\test.txt" using this code the content is printed with default paper size A4 . When the same file is printed using notepad++ or notepad chosing the same printer that java gets, the content is printed obeying the custom paper size defined on printer.

The custom paper size has a height of 7,5 cm. The content is thirty lines each with word test, when printed on java the content is printed continuously one underneath the other not respecting page division, when is printed with notepad++ the content is splited is 3 pages respecting page definition on printer settings.

What changes I have to do in this java code to use custom paper size defined on printer ?